# For a for loop bounded from 1 to n^2, and i doubling each time, how should the time complexity be expressed?

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I have a loop `for (int i = 1, i < n^2, i=2i)`. Since i doubles every iteration, and it goes from 1 to n^2, I think the time complexity is (n^2)/(2^n). However, it is supposed to be logarithmic. How should I reinterpret this loop?

Comment: By the way (n^2)/(2^n) in the denominator grows faster than the numerator, so you can quickly tell that something is wrong: as `n` grows the function would *speed up*

Answer (score 4):

The number of iterations is<sup>1</sup>:

<sup>⌈</sup>*log<sub>2</sub>(n<sup>2</sup>)*<sup>⌉</sup>

...which is:

<sup>⌈</sup>*2log<sub>2</sub>n*<sup>⌉</sup>

...which has an asymptotic complexity of:

*O(log n)*

---

<sup>1</sup> You can check manually that it is logarithmic in terms of *n²*, but maybe it helps to see this parallel:

The multiplication with 2 corresponds to a binary shift to the left, so that in binary notation `i` goes from 1 to 10 to 100 to 1000,...

This means the loop will stop iterating when the number of binary bits of `i` has exceeded the number of binary bits of *n²*. So the number of iterations corresponds to the number of binary bits of *n²*, which is logarithmic.

Answer (score 0):

The main mistake in your approach is that you've mixed up the interpretation of `n`.

- `n` is the independent variable appearing in the for loop `for (int i = 1, i < n^2, i=2i)`. That's where your numerator term `n^2` comes from.
- The iteration assigns to `i` values that are powers of 2. That's where you derived the `2^n` from, but this usage of `n` is not the same value as the original `n`. We should give the iteration count a different name, e.g. `k`. And this number of iterations happens to be the value we're interested in.

The iteration ends with the the smallest `k` matching the condition

2<sup>k</sup> >= n<sup>2</sup>

Some rewriting:
k >= log<sub>2</sub> n<sup>2</sup>
k >= 2 log<sub>2</sub> n

Eliminating the constant factors, we have O(logn).